# interfacing arduino uno with 9 dof razor imu

Tags: arduino, imu

I have followed the tutorial for razor IMU and it worked perfectly when the IMU is directly connected to the PC. Currently, i am trying to interface the 9 dof razor imu with the arduino uno by simply connect the rx to tx and tx to rx. Sadly, it doesn't work! So, i am just wondering, has anyone done this before? or can anybody give me some hints? Much appreciated!

Comment: Not a full answer, but a much cheaper way to accomplish the same thing; http://www.spiked3.com/?p=1731

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've already experience.
Check please the baud rate of Arduino. it must match that of the board. Pay attention to the connection 5V and ground. I mean...check them with a [Voltmeter](http://www.northerntool.com/images/product/2000x2000/163/163100_2000x2000.jpg) !!!!

After that try to connect only the Arduino to your PC and be sure it echoes all ASCII Charachter you send to it (for this you find a ton of progrs in net). It everything goes wonderful and you are sure is everything ok, try just to forwarding the raw data from the board to the PC.

Only if those steps don't show any sign of life have you a broken board or something like that.

Let us know